# Can i check if SMS was sent over IMS in Android?

Tags: android, sms, lte, ims

So SMS in HSPA is sent via the circuit switched network, rather than the data network, using the signalling space.
LTE is actually a bit more complex, as it moves from a circuit switched, to a packet switched world. LTE itself doesn't have a component for Voice or SMS, unless the Phone and network are VoLTE (Voice over LTE) and SMSoIP (SMS over IP) enabled. The technical requirements of which are outlined in GSMA IR.92 (http://www.gsma.com/newsroom/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/IR.92-v7.0.pdf). Essentially, if a phone and network are SMSoIP enabled (which requires VoLTE/IMS services to also be enabled), then the phone will send SMS using SIP

I was wondering if i can verify if a SMS was sent over IMS? All the packet switch SMS's are sent over IMS trough SMSC? Can i verify that in some way?

Edit: It's only sent over IMS if i have VoLTE / VoWifi enabled on device?, please correct me if i say something wrong.

Comment: Hey, you're correct, Volte=SIP sms, 2g,3g is MAP.
I am not aware that phone manufacturers offer distinction to the end user (specially since they still have lot's of Volte issues to solve) :)

Comment: Thankz Marvin, I didn't found nothing on phones to distinguish sms's, yeah, if you discover some other way to do it i would be very thankful if you share with me. 
One of my other problems is that i don't even have VoLTE network here in my country to try experiments :v.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have access to Device logs or if the SMS application explicitly shows the info on UI (highly unlikely)

Answer (score -2):

try service codes on your device, i'm sure many devices will allow you to change that specific option and even more sometimes, for instance permanent radio-off (celluar connectivity, so not even emergency can be called)